# How to fetch Azure Blob Content Using Java from Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk, azure-java-sdk

I am creating Azure function using Java, My requirement I need to copy blob from one container to another container with encryption

so, for encrypting blob I am adding 4bites before and after the blob while uploading to sink container

now, I need to fetch blob content, for this I found one class in azure i.e,

```
@BlobInput(
 name = "InputFileName", 
 dataType = "binary", 
 path = sourceContainerName+"/{InputFileName}") 
 byte[] content,
```

Here `byte[] content,` fetching content of blob

but I am facing some errors like, if I pass any file name as `InputFileName` parameter it is giving 200ok means returning successful. also it is difficult to mefor exception handling

so I am looking for other ways for fetching blob content.... please answer me if any methods or classes we have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for more control, instead of using the bindings, you can use the Azure Storage SDK directly. Check out the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli) doc for getting
setup.

[This sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/blob/BasicExample.java) has full end-to-end code that you could build upon. Here is the code that you are looking for in it for reference

```java
String data = "Hello world!";
InputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

/*
 * Create the blob with string (plain text) content.
 */
blobClient.upload(dataStream, data.length());

dataStream.close();

/*
 * Download the blob's content to output stream.
 */
int dataSize = (int) blobClient.getProperties().getBlobSize();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(dataSize);
blobClient.downloadStream(outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```